# building master-details grids using jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, datatables-1.10

i'm using jQuery datatable as grid now i want to display master details 
(orders - order details)
depending on master ID (ajax call to create the detail table)
all i found 
https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html
which is static string 
is my request possible ?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do ajax request before render extended row info.

Create a function that accept row info and callback which will render extended row info.

Inside a function do ajax callback and on success call render callback with formatted data.

Code example base on example link code:

```js
/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Full name:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.name+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extension number:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.extn+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extra info:</td>'+
            '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</table>';
}

function loadAjaxInfo(data, callback) {
    $.ajax({
      ...
      data: {/*Put your request needle here*/},
      ...
      success: function(response){
        callback(format(response));
      }
    })
}
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "../ajax/data/objects.txt",
        "columns": [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );
     
    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );
 
        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
          loadAjaxInfo(row.data(), function(formattedContent){
            // Open this row
            row.child(formattedContent).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
          });
        }
    } );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I add it only to formatted code example. Use it for implement your own logic

Comment: Sorry i will try it now and give you feedback

Comment: well it worked but not the way i wanted so what i want is the detail is to be a datatable has its own events sort - filter - search a true datatable is that possible since i will need to but a delete button on the details that will delete the selected detail that will not be easy on the html table  i hope there is a way thank you

Comment: `datatable` doesn't provide that possibility as I know. Try create datatable in `loadAjaxInfo` on `format(response)` return result. Or put some reference to generated code and try init on it datatable after executing `row.child(formattedContent).show();`