# Jquery datatable master-detail with grouping

Tags: jquery, datatables

I built a master-detail datatable using this [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43962060/building-master-details-grids-using-jquery-datatable), I also built a grouped datatable using the following [Example](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html).

When combining both examples to build a grouped table with master-detail, 
the detail does not show; the function return corrects HTML but it isn't rendered:

```
loadAjaxInfo(row.data(), function(formattedContent){
    // Open this row
    row.child(formattedContent).show();
    tr.addClass('shown');
});
```

`formattedContent` contains the correct HTML but I can't show it.

Edit 1
Full Script

```
function BindDataTmpTable() {
        var tmpcolumnArrayToHide = [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];

        var strSearchLang = "  بحث  ";
        if (lang == 'en-US') {
            strSearchLang = "  Search   ";
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: 'Query.asmx/FillTmpTransData',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: '{ }',

            success: function (data) {

                Tmptable = $('#TmpbasicTable').DataTable({
                    "aaData": JSON.parse(data.d),
                    "bFilter": true,
                    "paging": false,
                    "aaSorting": [],
                    "order": [[2, 'asc']],
                    "bInfo": false,
                    "lengthChange": false,
                    "oLanguage": {
                        "sSearch": strSearchLang
                    },
                    "columns": [
                  { "data": null }, { "data": "id" }, { "data": "Trans_No" },
                     { "data": "tmpDate" }, { "data": "Trans_Date" }, { "data": "TransDesc" },
                    { "data": "Trans_TypeName" }
                     , { "data": "Doc_TypeName" }, { "data": "Doc_Serial" }
                    , { "data": "Money" }, { "data": "Is_Periodic" }
                    , { "data": "Analitic" }, { "data": "Benifit_Id" }
                    , { "data": "Benifit_Name" }, { "data": "First_Pay" }
                    , { "data": "FirstPay_Allow_Period" }, { "data": "Agent_Commision" }

                    ],
                    "columnDefs": [
         {
             "targets": tmpcolumnArrayToHide,
             "visible": false,
             "searchable": true
         }, {
             "targets": 17,
             "data": null,
             "className": "FixedWidth",
             "defaultContent":
                     ' <button class="btn btnEdit" type="button"> <i class="fa fa-pencil " style="font-size:20px"></i> </button> <button class="btn btnDelete" type="button"> <i class="fa fa-trash " style="font-size:20px"></i> </button>'

         }, {
             "targets": 1,
             "className": "hide_column"

         }, {
             "targets": 0,
             "data": null,
             "defaultContent":
                     ' <button class="btn btnInfo" type="button"> <i class="fa fa-info" style="font-size:20px"></i> </button> '

         },
         {
             "targets": 10,
             "data": null,

             render: function (data, type, row) {
                 switch (data) {

                     case 1: return '<input type=\"checkbox\" onclick="return false" checked value="' + data + '">'; break;
                     case 0: return '<input type=\"checkbox\" onclick="return false"  value="' + data + '">'; break;

                 }


             },
             "defaultContent":
                 '<input type=\"checkbox\" onclick="return false"  value="' + data + '">'
         }
         ,


                    ],
                    "drawCallback": function (settings) {
                        var api = this.api();
                        var rows = api.rows({ page: 'current' }).nodes();
                        var last = null;

                        api.column(2, { page: 'current' }).data().each(function (group, i) {
                            if (last !== group) {
                                $(rows).eq(i).before(
                                    '<tr class="group"><td colspan="8">' + group + '</td></tr>'
                                );

                                last = group;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function (err) {
                // alert(err);
            }
        })
    }


     $('#TmpbasicTable tbody').on('click', '.btnInfo', function (e) {

            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var row = table.row(tr);

            if (row.child.isShown()) {
                // This row is already open - close it
                row.child.hide();
                tr.removeClass('shown');
            }
            else {
                loadAjaxInfoTmpSubTrans(tr[0].cells[1].innerHTML, function (formattedContent) {
                    // Open this row
                    row.child(formattedContent).show();
                    tr.addClass('shown');
                });
            }

        });
 function loadAjaxInfoTmpSubTrans(data, callback) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "Query.asmx/FilltmpSubTransData",
            data: '{TransID:0,tmpTransID: ' + data + '}',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (Result) {
                //ContractID = data.ContractId;
                //PeriodStartDate = data.ImportDate;
                //Deleted = data.ContractStatusId;

                callback(formatTmpSubTrans(Result.d));
            },
            error: function (Result) {

            }
        });
    }
    function formatTmpSubTrans(result) {
        // `d` is the original data object for the row


        var rows = " <thead><tr><th> رقم الحساب </th>" +
            "<th>اسم الحساب </th> <th> رقم السند </th>  " +
            "<th> الوصف </th> " +
            "<th> المدين </th> <th> الدائن  </th>  " +
            "<th>العملة  </th> <th> معامل التحويل  </th>  " +
            "<th>مدين محلي </th> <th> دائن محلي  </th>  " +
            "</tr> </thead> <tbody>";
        if (lang == 'en-US')
            rows = " <thead><tr><th> Account No  </th>" +
              "<th>Account Name </th> <th> Doc. No. </th>  " +
              "<th> Discription </th> " +
              "<th> Debit </th> <th> Credit  </th>  " +
              "<th>Currency  </th> <th> Extchange Rate </th>  " +
              "<th> Local Debit </th> <th> Local Credit   </th>  " +
              "</tr> </thead> <tbody>";
        var debit = 0;
        var credit = 0;


        for (i = 0; i < result.length; ++i) {
            debit = parseFloat(debit) + parseFloat(result[i].Local_Debit);
            credit = parseFloat(credit) + parseFloat(result[i].Local_Credit);

            rows += '<tr style="height:40px">' +
                '<td>' + result[i].Account_No + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + result[i].AccountName + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + result[i].Doc_No + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + result[i].Notes + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + result[i].Debit + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + result[i].Credit + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + result[i].CurrencyName + '</td>' +
                  '<td>' + result[i].Echange_Rate + '</td>' +
                  '<td>' + result[i].Local_Debit + '</td>' +
                   '<td>' + result[i].Local_Credit + '</td>' +
                '</tr>';

        }
        var color;
        var diff = parseFloat(debit) - parseFloat(credit);
        if (debit == credit)
            color = '#45f939';
        else
            color = 'rgba(241, 70, 4, 0.44)';
        return '<div class="datagrid"><table id="DetTable" style="width:100%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +

            rows
            + '<tr><td> </td><td></td><td></td><td></td>' +
        '<td> </td><td> </td><td></td><td></td>' +
          '<td>' + debit + '</td>' +
           '<td>' + credit + ' </td></tr>'
             + '<tr style="background-color:' + color + '"><td> </td><td></td><td></td><td></td>' +
        '<td> </td><td> </td><td></td><td></td>' +
          '<td> الفرق</td>' +
           '<td>' + diff + ' </td></tr>'
            + ' </tbody></table></div>';
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your whole script to render the datatable?

Comment: Full Script Added